# How to make my Drupal custome Service return data on GET?

Tags: 7, services

I have defined few Drupal custom Services and they are working fine
via POST requests. But one of them needs to be available via GET.

This one:

```
function rooms_services_services_resources() {
    return array(
        'api' => array(
            'actions' => array(
                'hotel_inventory' => array(
                    'help' => 'Inventory of all Hotels',
                    'callback' => 'rooms_services_hotel_inventory',
                    'access callback' => 'rooms_services_access_callback',
                    'access arguments append' => false,
                    'args' => array(
                        array(
                            'name' => 'params',
                            'optional' => true,
                            'source' => 'param',
                            'type' => 'struct',
                            'description' => 'all passed URL parameters'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

It's working fine when I am making a request via POST with headers:

```
`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
```

or

```
`Content-Type: application/json`
```

as those I have enabled in my REST Server...

How do I make it work via simple GET request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hook_menu()` would work well for this. And it sounds like you have already worked out some of the functions, so given that, something like this might work:

```
function rooms_services_menu(){
  $items['api/hotel-inventory'] = array(
    'title' => 'All Hotel Inventory',
    'page callback' => 'rooms_services_hotel_inventory',
    'access callback' => 'rooms_services_access_callback',
  );
} 

function rooms_services_hotel_inventory(){
  ...
  return $inventory; //or whatever you want the GET request to return
}
```

I imagine you could put this in the same module as your REST hooks.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is *you can't*, unfortunately (AFAIK). For all non *action* resources, the Services module assumes that they are part of the entity C.R.U.D. spectrum, and then decides what to do based on the HTTP method. For example:

```
POST = Create
GET = Retrieve
PUT = Update
DELETE = Delete
```

So unless you're building an entity C.R.U.D. layer, you'll have to use *POST* on the *actions* array. Alternatively you could use `hook_menu()` to make your own custom `page_callback` that outputs JSON, then it could be accessed over GET. Another alternative is to use something like *Views Datasource* and compose a *Views JSON* to output your data (also available via *GET*).

Answer (score 0):

rather than use an action , you could use the approach that is used in the documentation here: https://www.drupal.org/node/783460.
Essentially just like you have the CRUD operations,  create an 'index' operation.

Have a look at the node service too - that impliments an index service

call /endpoint/node - and it lists all nodes, it has parameters for fields, page size.

```
'index' => array(
      'help' => 'List all nodes',
      'callback' => 'rooms_services_hotel_inventory',
      'args' => array(
```

It seems the perfect fit for your inventory list.